# Integral test for convergence of $\sum_{n=11}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n^3 + 3)^{7/2}}$

Tags: calculus

Use the Integral Test to determine whether the series

$$\sum_{n=11}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n^3 + 3)^{7/2}}$$ converges.

What do I compare this with and what is dx?

Comment: Surely you have some thoughts on this. Please share.

Comment: well I figured that you can compare it with the function in integral form. And I know that DX is a real number because it converges I just don't know what steps to take to solve for DX.

Comment: You don't "solve" for $dx$. Look back in the notes or textbook on examples of applying the integral test. When you've digested them, write down the integral you want to compare this sum to and we'll help if you're stuck again.

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to bother integral test. Or is it better to give an upper bound for summand first then use integral test? (then it becomes an integral test for the famous $n^{-p}$ series.)

Comment: @Solitary Agree, but if that is the instructions for the problem, we're stuck with it.